# Live input update in HTML with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm writing a HTML interface for a FPGA board. At the moment, I need to click somewhere outside the input box before the code under 'blur' gets executed (that is, the input values get send to the FPGA). What I want to do is to make the code in the 'blur' event in the jQuery executes at the same time as I change the input.

I have tried using 'focus' instead of 'blur' but that doesn't work.

I have tried the 'keyup' event instead of 'keydown', but in this case, the function(e) doesn't work.

I have also implemented a 'keydown' event such that I can select and increment/decrement the input digit using the arrow keys to update the input.

Here is the relevant sections of the code.

### jQuery

```
$('#gen_ch1_ampl')
  .on('focus paste', function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass('input-group');
    $('#apply_gen_ch1_ampl').show();
  })
  .on('blur', function() {
    $('#apply_gen_ch1_ampl').hide();
    $(this).parent().removeClass('input-group');

    var val = parseLocalFloat($(this).val());
    if(! isNaN(val)) {
      params.local.gen_sig_amp_ch1 = val;
      sendParams();
    }
    else {
      $(this).val(params.local.gen_sig_amp_ch1)
    }
    user_editing = false;
  })

  .on('keydown', function(e) {
    var curPos = this.selectionStart;
    var endPos = this.selectionEnd;
    if(curPos !== endPos) {
      createSelection(this, curPos, curPos+1);
    }

    if(e.keyCode == 37){
      curPos--;
      gotCode=true;
    }
    if(e.keyCode == 39){
      curPos++;
      gotCode=true;
    }
    var before = $(this).val().substring(0,curPos);
    var after = $(this).val().substring(curPos+1);
    var cur = Number($(this).val().substring(curPos, curPos+1));


    if(curPos < $(this).val().length) {
      if(e.keyCode == 38) {
        cur++;
        if(cur > 9) cur = 0;
        $(this).val(before + '' + cur + '' + after);
        gotCode=true;
      }
      if(e.keyCode == 40) {
        cur--;
        if(cur < 0) cur = 9;
        $(this).val(before + '' + cur + '' + after);
        gotCode=true;
      }
    }
    if(!gotCode) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }

    var field = this;
    window.setTimeout(function(){
      createSelection(field, curPos, curPos+1);
    }, 10);
  });



function createSelection(field, start, end) {
   if( field.createTextRange ) {
       var selRange = field.createTextRange();
       selRange.collapse(true);
       selRange.moveStart('character', start);
       selRange.moveEnd('character', end);
       selRange.select();
   } else if( field.setSelectionRange ) {
       field.setSelectionRange(start, end);
   } else if( field.selectionStart ) {
       field.selectionStart = start;
       field.selectionEnd = end;
   }
}
```

### HTML

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" onsubmit="return false;">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="gen_ch1_ampl" class="col-xs-4 control-label">Amplitude:</label>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-5">
      <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" value="0.00" id="gen_ch1_ampl">
    </div>
    <div style="padding: 7px 0 0;" class="col-xs-2" id="gen_ch1_ampl_units">Vpp</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `keyup` event. https://api.jquery.com/keyup/

Answer (score 1):

There is a beautiful event `'input'`. It is triggered each time you change the input field. Works also on the `textarea` tag

[Input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input)

Answer (score 0):

you can call the event at key up and mouse click event so that as soon as user writes any thing or paste anything using the mouse the event would be triggered